# Get repository in a custom validator class in Nest.js and TypeORM

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to make a custom decorator validator using class-validator in a Nest.JS project.

This is the code of the decorator

```js
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import {
  registerDecorator,
  ValidationOptions,
  ValidatorConstraint,
  ValidatorConstraintInterface,
  ValidationArguments,
} from 'class-validator';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Parking } from '../entities/parking.entity';

@ValidatorConstraint({ async: true })
export class UniqueNameConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Parking) private parkingRepository: Repository<Parking>,
  ) {}

  validate(name: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
    // This line is my problem, the repository is not initialized, it's null.
    const parkingLoader = this.parkingRepository.findOne({ where: { name } });

    return parkingLoader.then((parking) => {
      if (parking) return false;
      return true;
    });
  }
}

export function UniqueName(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return function (object: object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      constraints: [],
      validator: UniqueNameConstraint,
    });
  };
}
```

Now, I have the following DTO:

```js
@InputType()
export class CreateEntityInput {
  @UniqueName({ message: 'The name already exists' })
  @Field(() => String, { description: 'Name of the entity' })
  name: string;
}
```

And this entity:

```js
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Entity {
    @Column()
    @Field(() => String, { description: 'Name of the entity' })
    name: string;
}
```

All I would like to know is how to get the repository inside the validator class? how to retrieve data or make a SQL call using typeORM?

The repository is always null in this code.

I'm guessing it is because it's outside Nest.js container or something like that.

I need some guidance on this topic.

Since the conection has already been defined in the `app.module.ts` like this:

```js
const typeOrm = TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'database',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'postgres',
  database: 'postgres',
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: true,
});
```

I would really like to reuse it, but if there is no way to do it, at least I would like to know how to query to the database using typeORM from the validator class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add import at module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Parking])
  ],
  providers: [
    UniqueNameConstraint
  ]
```

and make UniqueNameConstraint @Injectable()